# Calculating fine structure constant for $Z$ boson energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

is there any explicit way to show that fine structure constant $\alpha_{m_Z}$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{127}$? All data that I've found rely upon experimental data. I also found this formula $$\alpha(s) = \dfrac{\alpha(0)}{1 - \Delta \alpha(s)}$$
but I fail too see how this formula should be applied.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377440/where-does-the-fine-structure-constant-come-from

Comment: A lengthy theoretical calculation in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0011135) gets 127.843 ± 0.039 for the reciprocal. See equation (82). It takes into account the vacuum polarization due to various virtual particles carrying electric charge.